# Unable to get llm_calls_summary while using NemoGuardrails

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I am trying to make use of Nemo-Guardrails, and am following the tutorial listed on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo-Guardrails/blob/develop/docs/getting_started/2_core_colang_concepts/README.md

Here are my config files:

1. `config.yml`

```
models:
  - type: main
    engine: openai
    model: gpt-3.5-turbo
```

2. `rails.co`

```
define user express greeting
  "Hello"
  "Hi"
  "Wassup?"

define bot express greeting
  "What's up"

define bot ask how are you
  "How are you doing?"

define flow greeting
  user express greeting
  bot express greeting
  bot ask how are you
```

And here is my main file:

```
from nemoguardrails import RailsConfig, LLMRails


config = RailsConfig.from_path("./config")
rails = LLMRails(config=config)


response = rails.generate(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "what is the capital of France?",
        }
    ]
)
info = rails.explain()
print(response)
print(info.colang_history)
print(info.llm_calls)

print(info.print_llm_calls_summary())
```

Based on the guide, my understanding is that since the request "What is the capital of France?" was not defined in the `rails.co`, it should make a call to the LLM, and return something like shown in the guide:

**Expected**
`Summary: 1 LLM call(s) took 0.48 seconds and used 524 tokens.

1. Task `generate_user_intent` took 0.48 seconds and used 524 tokens.
   `

**Actual result**
`No LLM calls were made. (from print(info.llm_calls)) None (from info.print_llm_calls_summary())`

May I know how I can alter my code, such that info.print_llm_calls_summary() would reflect that 1 LLM call has been made?